# Want to get the tag of current axes

Tags: matlab

I want to get the tag of current axes in GUI made through Matlab GUIDE.

The following code returns an empty matrix:

```
handle=gca;
get (handle,'tag')
```

Comment: Does a new figure window open up when you use `handle = gca`?

Comment: Actually I am using this in a callback and GUI is created using Guide.

Comment: No extra Window opens

Comment: Is the GUI window active when this callback run?

Comment: Yes it's active

Comment: A tag of axis in GUI that was created by GUIDE should not be changed, so you don't need to do it programmatically. You can type "guide name_of _GUI" (name of the fig file), then click on the axis area, and you see the tag name in the left bottom corner. Or, you can open the `property inspector`.

Comment: Sorry your answer is irrelevant

Comment: Were the axes added in GUIDE or are you spawning them with a callback function? If the former, have you verified that the axes has a tag using the property inspector in GUIDE?

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for which you get an empty matrix could be because the property `HandleVisibility` of the GUI `figure` and / or of the `axes` is set to 'off`.

In order to get the `Tag` property of the `axes` object, as well as the ones of any other object in the GUI the `HandleVisibility` property has to be `on'.

Once that property is `on`, there are several options to get the `Tag` of the axes within a GUI callback:

By using the `get` function

```
% Get the current axes tag
get(gca,'tag')
```

By using the `dot notation`

```
% Get the current axes with the "dot notation"
c_ax=gca
c_ax.Tag
```

In case there are more than one `axes` in your GUI, you can use the [findobj](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) function to get all the `axes` hanldes, then, you can use a`for` loop to get the `Tag`:

```
% Get the handle of all the axes object in the GUI
ax_list=findobj(gcf,'type','axes')
% Get the tagf of all the axes object in the GUI
for i=1:length(ax_list)
   ax_list(i).Tag
end
```

Comment: I have opened the axes property inspector and Visible property is on/checked.

Comment: The `Visible` property is used to show / hide the GUI object, you chould check the `HandleVisibility` property. Did you tryied to insert one of the solutions in the callback code?

Comment: c_ax=gca; c_ax.Tag returns an empty matrix; I have to display 58 data set on a figure thus 15 axes are used to display 15 data sets at a time and remaining are displayed with next and back buttons. User can randomly select any axis to set data limits with mouse. I need to know which axes is being selected so that could be used the limits received via ginput and change the data of that particular axes. If tag is known when an axis is clicked then its good otherwise I shall get the axes information by data set indicator and axes position attribute